# How to get rid of the auto folder with .el files?

Tags: latex, auctex

I'm using Emacs 25.1, and I use it primarily for LaTeX with AucTeX. Some time ago in the directories of my .tex files, there started to appear a folder named "auto" with .el files in it. The .el files look like this:

```
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "nameoffile"
 (lambda ()
   (TeX-add-to-alist 'LaTeX-provided-class-options
                     '(("article" "11pt")))
   (TeX-run-style-hooks
    "latex2e"
    "article"
    "art11"
    "amsmath"
    "amssymb")
   (TeX-add-symbols
    "R"
    "Z")
 :latex)
```

EDIT: So I found out that this is probably triggered by enabling parse on save. Is there a way to stop automatically generating these files?

Answer (score 5):

You can disable parsing when you save your file with this line in your init file:

```lisp
(setq TeX-auto-save nil)
```

Now you can trigger parsing with <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> manually.  When you do this, AUCTeX will still save a `docname.el` in a subdirectory `auto`.  If you dislike this, you can set the variable `TeX-auto-private` to a directory of your choice.  AUCTeX will then save all parsing information in that directory.  The drawback is that you get confusing completion if you have different files in different directories with the same file name.